# Who are the main developers of Ethereum?

Tags: foundation

Bitcoin has a handful of core developers like Gavin, Mike Hern, and etc that are the gatekeepers to implementing core features depending on community feedback. Who are the core devs in Ethereum and which parts of Ethereum are they responsible for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the roles of ETHDEV, ETHCORE and the Ethereum Foundation?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/467/what-are-the-roles-of-ethdev-ethcore-and-the-ethereum-foundation)

Comment: I do not agree that this is a duplicate. The question 5chdn referenced is organizational and duckx's question is about individual contribution at any level.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the [main developers of Ethereum](http://ethdev.com/#team)

To know the actual contributions, you can look at individual projects. For example, here is a list of major contributors involving in making Ethereum Wallet (which runs in Mist) possible:

[Ethereum Wallet dapp](https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/graphs/contributors)

[Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/graphs/contributors)

[web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/graphs/contributors)

[Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/graphs/contributors)

[Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/graphs/contributors)

[Yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper/graphs/contributors)

(The above is not an exhaustive list of all Ethereum projects - this is just Ethereum Wallet. There's also Alethzero, C++ client, EthereumJ implementations...)

---

[All official Ethereum projects/repositories (Github)](https://github.com/ethereum)